# How to repeat last command parameter in ZSH

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, readline

I often need to move file from one location to other, but it requires copying and pasting huge part of the command. For example:

```
mv ~/Projects/foo/bar/baz.img ~/Projects/foo/bar/fiz.dmg
```

Is it possible after entering `~/Projects/foo/bar/baz.iso` part of above command to use some shortcut that duplicates it so I can change the very end to `fiz.dmg`?

Comment: this has nothing to do with programming. More appropirate to superuser.com. That said, doesn't `!$` give you the last word of the previous cmd? Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need this:

```
mv ~/Projects/foo/bar/baz.img ~/Projects/foo/bar/fiz.dmg
```

easily turns into

```
mv ~/Projects/foo/bar/{baz,fiz}.img
```

. Note: zsh completion is still available when you write `{` (unless you have a habit of writing closing `}` right away) if you want it.

Comment: Succeeded to write the answer a few (eight) seconds before question was closed.

Answer (score 1):

I actually discovered one possible solution. Just press:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> few times and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> two times (and space between pastes).